# How much does repairing lost points of a ship's armor cost?

Tags: traveller, vehicles, mongoose-traveller

On page **143** of the **Core Rulebook** (Traveller Mongoose) under section **Repairs** it specifies how and how much to repair Hull Damage, Structure Damage and System Damage, but there is no mention of Armor Points, that indeed can be damaged by the result of 7 on the **Ship's Damage Location Table** (page **151**) that specifies armor is reduced by one, and if Armour is already 0 then this counts as Hull hit.

Appreciated RAW, RAI and rules from other editions, I'm interested on the economic part of it, so other editions should use similar prices as is the same universe, as House Rule I'm actually using the same rule as for Hull Hits (1-6 Hours, 1 ton of spare parts), but I feel some cost should be added, or at least the cost of this "1 ton of spare parts" that I feel it should be specified for Hull case too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Costs could be a simple extrapolation of the rules given:
Titanium costs 5% of the base hull per 2 points of armor
Crystal Iron costs 20% of the base hull for 4 points of armor
Bonded Superdense costs 50% of the base hull for 6 points of armor

Titanium = 2.5% base cost of hull / point
Crystal Iron = 5% base hull / point
Bonded Superdense = 8.33% base hull /point

This gets expensive, though this could be the cost you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the rulebook for the 100th time I have found this:

> **Page 138 Core Rulebook:**
>   For the effects of damage see page 150. For details about repairing
>   damage, see page 143. *Repair supplies cost Cr. 10,000/ton.*

So it seems that the repairs need a Mechanics skill check, 1-6 hours, a ton of parts per point and 10,000 Cr. per ton of supplies.

Comment: That's per ton of supplies, not per ton of armour to be repaired. The weight of cargo is important in Traveller.

Comment: But is the only reference I found about a cost associated to repairs, there is no armor specific, and in Hull Repairs only specifies time and the need of "1 ton of spare parts"